# Are there any Ubuntu tablets that can be purchased?

Tags: hardware

Is there a tablet that can be purchased with Ubuntu or what tablets are suggested for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but it will be spring 2014.  The Intermatrix U7 may well be a genuine product backed by a genuine company. But at barely a month post-tablet reveal, it’s a little too early to take cash upfront for something that won’t be available for potentially another year.

[See World’s First Ubuntu Tablet” Starts Taking Pre-Orders](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/worlds-first-ubuntu-tablet-starts-taking-pre-orders-but-is-it-legit)

But [if You Have a Nexus 7](http://news.yahoo.com/ubuntu-now-available-tablets-nexus-7-172300246.html), you can have it now

See [Ubuntu Touch prepped for 20+ smartphones and tablets](http://www.zdnet.com/ubuntu-touch-prepped-for-20-smartphones-and-tablets-7000011851/)